# How to determine number of characters that GetNonZeroBytes & Pbkdf2 will produce, so I can configure size of database field that will hold this value?

Tags: c#, .net

I am exploring cryptographic technique to create the salt and hash passwords.

Sample 1:

```
    // generate a 128-bit salt using a cryptographically strong random sequence of nonzero values
    byte[] pSalt = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(pSalt);
    }                  
    
    string strSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(pSalt)
```

Sample 2:

```
    // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA256 with 100,000 iterations)
    var pHash = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: Convert.FromBase64String(pSalt),
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
            iterationCount: 100000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8);

    string strHash = Convert.ToBase64String(pHash)
```

For both the strings (strSalt and strHash) from samples above, can we deterministically conclude the size (number of characters) in the final string?

Comment: You know the size of `pHash`/`pSalt` as you requested it to be of 256/128 bit. So your question is if the Base64 representation of a byte array of known fixed size is fixed? The answer would be "yes".

Comment: What is the calculation to convert the bit value into Base64 string value to conclude the length of the string?

Comment: Base64 encodes 6 bits in one character, so to encode N bytes, you need 8/6*N characters (round up if required)

Comment: So character count of 43 and 22 for 256 and 128 bit respectively? If you could put it in an answer then I can mark it answerd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes 6 bits in one character, so to encode N bit, you need N/6 characters (round up if required).

The .NET method [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string) will append additional padding characters (`=`) to make the length a multiple of 4, so if you use this method, round up to the next multiple of 4.

`Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[128/8]).Length` will be 24.

`Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[256/8]).Length` will be 44.